# How to download a file to a specific location?

Tags: windows, autoit

I want to download an image to the "Music" folder but it downloads to where AutoIt (.exe) is placed. If AutoIt.exe is in "Desktop" folder it will download to there.

My code:

```
Local $hDownload = InetGet("https://media.com/abc.jpg", "abc.jpg", 1, 1)
Sleep(250)
Do
    Sleep(250)
Until InetGetInfo($hDownload, $INET_DOWNLOADCOMPLETE)
Sleep(1000)
```

I want to download the image to my desired location.

Comment: Try to place yours exe file and the downloaded file in "ProgramFilesx86" folder. In my experience: It is very suspicious for antivirus software, the case of putting exe files on the desktop.

Answer (score 1):

just give it the fully qualified filename (including the path):

```
Local $hDownload = InetGet("https://media.com/abc.jpg","C:\my desired\folder\abc.jpg", 1 , 1)
```

It's better readable and maintainable when you use variables. The following code works for me:

```
$url="https://www.google.de/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"
$file=@StartupDir&"\test.png"
$hDownload=InetGet($url,$file)
if $hDownload = 0 then ConsoleWrite("Download failed." & @CRLF)
```

Comment: Maybe you forgot to insert the backslash between `@StartupDir` and the file name? See if my edit helps.

Comment: yes. it was my fault. now i fixed it and working now. thanks for your time